# How to integrate Hudson and MantisBT

Tags: hudson, mantis

**Hudson** is a popular CI system, **Mantis** is a popular Bug Tracking system.

I have a list of project in Mantis and **I would like to import into Hudson in order to build specific project**.

In othet words, I configured a parametric job which accept the project name from a choice list, then the job connect the svn repository and check out it. I woul like to choose the project from mantis project list.

Is it possible and How?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would achieve this. Hudson builds projects based on their location in the source control management system - Subversion, Git, etc . Mantis doesn't typically hold source control information so information can't be pulled from there.

Comment: clarified, more info, t2u

Answer (score 0):

as pointed by Robert it is a little bit complex, because the mantsiBT uses local database;  to do you can use the [*Extended choice parameter*](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) which get data from a properties file or url, than you can the following page into the mantisbt home directory:

```
<?php

require_once ('core.php');

$link = mysql_connect($g_hostname, $g_db_username, $g_db_password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db('bugtracker')) {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}


    $result1 = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM bugtracker.mantis_project_table');


if (!$result1) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
} else {

    echo 'projects=';
    for ($j = 0; $j < mysql_num_rows($result1); ++$j) {
        $vv0 = mysql_result($result1, $j, 0);
        if ($j == 0) {
            echo $vv0;
        } else {
            echo ',' . $vv0;
        }
    }

}
echo "\r\n";

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

and it works for me.

In the extended choice plugin

- select `Single Select`
- set the `page url of mantisbt` just defined into the file parameter
- set property key to `projects`